# GDAL command alternative in dzsave

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I am new to dzsave (libvips) library. Before I stumbled upon this I was using GDAL to tile images. I decided to look into dzsave because GDAL was taking 40 seconds even after using the --process flag to tile a colored image .

Will it be fast if I do the same process using dzsave library?

Also, I was not able to find some required flags in dzsave. These are the commands which I used to generate tiles using GDAL,

Github-link :[libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips)

Website-link: [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/)

**To generate VRT file with coordinates :**

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 12.88375724563124 74.83986362864423 12.883615511245678 74.840137447214213 foo.png foo.vrt
```

**To generate tiles:**

```
gdal2tiles.py --processes=2 foo.vrt
```

I want to achieve the same process using dzsave.

Comment: Convert your foo.png into a tiled geotiff and have another try with gdal2tiles. It may be faster especially if your png is big. Just to make sure that you are optimizing the right thing.

Comment: Yes, I will try that and let you know @user30184

Comment: Just checked it now it took 7 seconds. Thank you so much for your help. But won't this be even faster using the libvips library?

Comment: I don't know, I have never tried. Report back when you have done your tests. But testing is difficult and you should know how to do things in a right way for libvips.

Comment: Tiling without providing coordinates I was able to do using libvips and it took like 1 second. I was not able to figure out how to pass coordinates and do the same